# Is it possible to load data on Spark workers directly into Apache Arrow in-memory format without first loading it into Spark's in-memory format?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pyarrow

We have a use case for doing a large number of vector multiplications and summing the results such that the input data typically will not fit into the RAM of a single host, even if using 0.5 TB RAM EC2 instances (fitting OLS regression models). Therefore we would like to:

1. Leverage PySpark for Spark's traditional capabilities (distributing the data, handling worker failures transparently, etc.)
2. But also leverage C/C++-based numerical computing for doing the actual math on the workers

The leading path seems to be to leverage Apache Arrow with PySpark, and use Pandas functions backed by NumPy (in turn written in C) for the vector products. However, I would like to load the data directly to Arrow format on Spark workers. The existing PySpark/Pandas/Arrow documentation seems to imply that the data is in fact loaded into Spark's internal representation first, then converted into Arrow when Pandas UDFs are called: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/sql-pyspark-pandas-with-arrow.html#setting-arrow-batch-size

I found one related paper to this in which the authors developed a zero-copy Arrow-based interface for Spark, so I take it that this is a highly custom thing to do not currently supported in Spark: [https://users.soe.ucsc.edu/~carlosm/dev/publication/rodriguez-arxiv-21/rodriguez-arxiv-21.pdf](https://users.soe.ucsc.edu/%7Ecarlosm/dev/publication/rodriguez-arxiv-21/rodriguez-arxiv-21.pdf)

I would like to ask if anyone knows of a simple way other than what is described in this paper. Thank you!